# Has Anyone Successfully Embedded a Matplotlib Graph Inside An FLTKHS GUI?

Tags: matplotlib, haskell, fltk

I am new to both FLTKHS and the Haskell matplotlib library, so please forgive if question is dumb.

FLTK is C++ under the hood.

matlplotlib is Python under the hood.

It seems to me that passing a handle for the graph into the GUI frame might not work well.

On the other hand, the Haskell community has come up with a lot of clever solutions before, so maybe it works just fine.

Has anyone successfully done this?

If so, can you post a short example that illustrates how you did it?